# How to make a gif stop without click anything in JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, gif

The gif plays after entering the frame but how to make it stop automatically after it finished playing once (something like a video) ? I want it to stop at the last frame of the gif not completely close the frame after it has been played.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a gif run once and stop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592551/how-to-make-a-gif-run-once-and-stop-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

use JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

```
        URL img = this.getClass().getResource("src/image.gif");
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel gif = new JLabel(icon);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("gif");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```